# Decoupled version of hash_map/unordered_map

Tags: c++, embedded, hashmap, unordered-map, std

I'm writing an embedded application, and the environment I use does not, unfortunately, have C++11 support at present.

I need to implement a hash/unordered map (a regular `std::map` won't do for performance reasons), but can't seem to find a way to do it cleanly.

Boost doesn't want to work without bringing in practically the whole library. Even the original STL `hash_map` from SGI wants several headers, and duplicates standard library functionality, causing ambiguous function calls. It's a real mess.

For ease of implementation, versioning, quality control, V&V, etc. I really need something that leverages the existing standard library and exists in only a few header files that I can put right in the same folder as all the other source/header files. Does such a thing exist, or am I without hope? I've searched for a long while, but have come up empty-handed.

Thanks very much for any help. I can certainly clarify further if necessary.

Comment: Did you try using a `std::map` with a custom allocator?  That probably fixes all your performance problems right there.

Comment: My problem is that I am constantly removing/placing new elements from/in the map. If it has to reorder things each time this occurs, it's too slow. Can that be solved with a custom allocator? Sorry for my ignorance there, I've never used anything but `std::allocator` before.

Comment: I've never had a case where balancing caused a noticeable performance problem.  Are you _certain_ that's the case?  RB-Tree balancing is quite fast, and it only balances when the tree is _very_ lopsided.

Comment: Does your environment have `stdext::hashmap` or similar?  MSVC has had it for over 10 years.

Comment: Sorry, no, I am not certain. I just know that it's slow and that I remove/place new elements quite a bit. I have read that the "unorderedness"/hashing as opposed to a sorting-based approach is the primary performance advantage of these new containers over regular maps/sets, is that not true?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, there is no `stdext` or similar in the environment. I would guess that because it is for embedded systems and is more niche there are far fewer extensions in general.

Comment: In _some cases_, the unorderedness can be faster.  In some other cases, hash maps are much slower.  It depends on a lot of factors.  I think the unordered has a tendency to be faster in the general case.

Comment: Okay, I will try a custom allocator then and see if that solves the problem. Thanks very much for the idea.

Comment: Try [Google Sparsehash](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/) or [MCT](https://launchpad.net/libmct/). Both are small libraries with hashmaps, but they implement closed hashing, unlike `std::unordered_map` — may or may not be a problem, see comparisons.

Comment: The bit of EASTL that's been released might have something worth taking a look at as well: https://github.com/paulhodge/EASTL

Comment: @MichaelBurr That looks very interesting. I had heard of EA's version of the STL before, but never taken a look. Thanks very much for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the GNU implementation? On my Ubuntu Machine, unordered_map.h does not include anything. This file is located at

```
    /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/unordered_map.h
```

which is about 400 lines although the file "unordered_map" in /usr/include/c++/4.6/ has more headers but you can tweak those I guess.

I think you can find the source code for implementation from GNU.org (?) and compile it yourself?

Comment: I will check this out on my Ubuntu as well, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Sorry this took me so long to check out...I think you are right that it's really the `unordered_map` file in the top level folder that needs to be included, but I think some tweaking should keep the total number of files I have to bring in down. In any case this is much better than using the old SGI STL. Thanks again.